# Opening a link from Angular material-autocomplete?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular for my project and I've created a searchbox. I would like to be able to click on the dropdown options so that when I click on the option it opens a link. This is the HTML for the options.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Is there a simple way to make it so that the options can be clicked and open a link? Or will I have to use a (click) event in some capacity? What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `a` or `button` tag in your mat-option element.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">{{option}}</a>
</mat-option>
```

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaljlkxaorrk?file=src/app/autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html

Comment: Is it possible to make options a key value pair so that specific options will lead to specific websites? When I tried to implement this I ended up getting a number of errors saying options had to be of String[] type. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you refer this, It may help you
Ref: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbamqydbxol?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts